# LogicApp HTTP Handling non 200 response without the app failing

Tags: http, azure-logic-apps

I have a logic app which grabs some info, iterates over the information and then makes some HTTP requests.

Some of these requests will succeed, and it is expected some will fail from time to time.

I would like the logic app to "not fail" just because sometimes a get request will fail when we're okay for that to happen.

The reason this is important is that we're looping over an array of values.
Each GET request is partly formed from the data item we are iterating over.

We want the requests which a successful to continue working and basically ignore errors.

The loop is like this

```
Get list of IDs
FOR EACH ID
  GET REQUEST
  IF FAIL CONTINUE
NEXT ID
```

At the end of the run, the app is marked as success and all IDs in the list have had a GET request.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the answer

The step after the one which can fail HTTP in this case.

Click on the three vertical dots on where the options item lives.
Then click on run after

[image]

Remember this is on the step after the step which can fail

Comment: I could not find anything like this there is only delete or add note in my options